# Ternary expression which "does nothing" (noop) if the condition is false?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, ternary-operator

Out of curiosity I started wondering if it's possible to have a ternary expression that, if it evaluates to false, does nothing in the false branch.

Ie is there a way to write something like this:

```
variable = (someBool) ? i : <do nothing>;
```

As opposed to:

```
if (someBool) {
    variable = i;
}
```

I tried `((void)0)` or `while(false){};` as no-op but the compiler expects an expression.

**UPDATE:**

I realized the question lost some meaning because I tried to make the code easier. The initial idea I had was to initialize a static var with a ternary - using the static var itself as the condition:

```
static int var = (var != 0) ? var = 1 : (var already initialized, do nothing);
```

This is assuming that uninitialized variables are initialized to 0 which is not always true (or never in release builds, not quite sure). So maybe it's a hypothetical question.

Comment: If the variable is static, then the question doesn't make any sense. Because the initializing expression of a variable with static storage duration must always be a constant expression, in any version of the C standard. Also, static storage duration variables are _always_ initialized to 0 in any version of the C standard.

Comment: Assignment and initialization are really two different things in C and  an initializer of a static variable is only evaluated before all code execution.

Comment: (And the same remarks are also true for C++)

Comment: Actually, no, they're not. In C++ the initializing expression for a variable of static storage duration can be anything, as long as it's itself initialized. E.g. `rand()` is OK, although probably unseeded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

how about [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)?

```
int variable = 0;
bool cond = true; // or false

(cond && (variable = 42));

printf("%d\n", variable);
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far that has addressed OP's request. +1.

Comment: One of the languages in the tags is C#. This is invalid in C# (and not just because of the printf).

Comment: interesting approach, odd construct but surprisingly the compiler likes it (removed C# from tags, that didn't really belong in there, I'm using Objective-C so C/C++ should work too but not C#)

Comment: @DeeMac: The `printf` wont work in C# but the rest should be fine

Comment: It doesn't like: (cond && (variable = 42)); Shame, there's a million instances I could use this. "Only assignment....can be used as a statement"

Comment: @DeeMac: oh yeah, completely misread that part. Anyway, I still think `if(cond) variable = 42;` is better. It is short enough, and it is very readable and easy to understand

Comment: Maybe helpful for someone.
Can be written without any external brackets: `cond && (variable = 42);`

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
variable = (someBool) ? i : variable ;
```

Though I would personally prefer the original if statement

Comment: good point but in my particular case (I simplified the code which lost the point apparently) I try to init a static variable and the compiler says "suspicious use of static variable in its own initialization" or something to that effect

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Well the compiler is right. If you're going to init a static variable, you can't read its value before you assign it.

Comment: I know, that's when I started to wonder. ;) Especially because the expression was: static int var = (var != 0) ? var = 1 : (var already initialized, do nothing);

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I'm pretty sure you can read its value, because static objects are 0-initialized prior to their initialization. Can't remember whether that's just in file and class scope, though, or also in function scope.

Answer (score 4):

Compilers not only expect *expression*, but the expression the returns `type` on the left side (the type of `variable` whatever is it). So, no you can not do that.  It's not *conditional execution*, but `variable` member assignment.

These are *completely* different things. 
In second example :

```
if (someBool) {
    variable = i;
}
```

you do not assign anything, but simply execute based on condition. So in *your* case, where you don't want *to do* anything (not *assign* anything), the way to go is conditional execution so use simply the second case.

Comment: Why would the compiler expect anything from the OP's question to return a boolean? The returned type of a ?: expression is the type of the 2nd and 3rd operands (2nd and 3rd are balanced against each other).

Comment: @Lundin: good point, I wrongly validated the code of OP. Corrected answer to meet more precisely provided question.

Answer (score 2):

The format of the [conditional expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is

```
<expression> ? <expression> : <expression>
```

In other words, it *must* have some expression.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question. E.g. in C++ any expression may throw, which would NOT initialize the left-hand side.

Comment: @MSalters I posted this answer before the update. But even if the expression throws, there must be *some* expression for the code to even compile.

Comment: True, but that can be a `throw-expression`, i.e. `true ? throw 1 : "Foo"`.

Comment: @MSalters Huh. Didn't know throw could be an expression in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing your edit: in C99 variables of static scope are initialised to 0.  However, I have never really trusted that because I've been programming in C since the K&R days.

Anyway, just initialise the variable.  As the variable is static, it's only going to happen once during the whole execution time of the program.

Comment: so something like: static int var = someComplexFunction(); will execute the complex function only once? Is this guaranteed even within the scope of a function (as opposed to global scope)? I mean static is static, would make sense if function runs only once.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: It's guaranteed in single-threaded programs, with multiple threads there's a potential race condition. When threading is introduced in C++11 and C11 I can't remember whether thread-safe initialization of statics is guaranteed or not, but (a) your code isn't thread-safe anyway, so is no better than relying on the implementation; (b) prior to C11 and C++11, some implementations did thread-safe init and others didn't, but they generally documented which it was, so you can find out.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D In C99 `static int var = someComplexFunction();` would be illegal.  Initialisers for statics have to be constant expressions or string literals.  This makes the thread safetyness moot.

Comment: @SteveJessop *"When threading is introduced in C++11 and C11 I can't remember whether thread-safe initialization of statics is guaranteed or not"* - It is, by standard (which of course still says nothing about practical support by major compilers).

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
variable = !someBool ?: i;
```

Since the ?: will no-op when the if expression is true but assign i if it's false.

Note: This has only been tested in Obj-C

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(someBool) ? (variable = i) : NULL;
```

Comment: @self. yeah assuming variable is an `int`. http://ideone.com/2urC8H or http://ideone.com/lYz1dV

Comment: I'll downvote too, because it is not "valid C", it is UB C. Should you write `variable = (someBool) ? (variable = i) : NULL;` you invoke undefined behavior. There is a sequence point after the evaluation of the control expression, but then you do `variable = (variable = i)`. The variable is modified twice with no sequence point in between, the left side and right side are unsequenced in relation to each other. Also, you only get away with having NULL as 3rd parameter because NULL evaluates to the integer value 0, even though sanity demands that NULL should only be used with pointers.

Comment: @Lundin While your sentiments against the third operand make sense, I haven't seen the answer write `variable = (someBool) ? (variable = i) : NULL;` in any way, which would indeed be plain rubbish.

Comment: @ChristianRau Because the only case where it makes sense to use the ?: operator is when you want a one-line assignment of something. In every other case, the ?: operator just adds obfuscation. Why write something unreadable when you can write readable code? "The C language allows it" is the lamest excuse you can give, because C is not a rational, sane language.

Comment: @Lundin *"Because the only case where it makes sense to use the ?: operator is when you want a one-line assignment of something. In every other case, the ?: operator just adds obfuscation."* - True, of course. Yet that doesn't validate your comment that incorrectly assumed the answer *did* use it in the *"only case where it makes sense"*.

Comment: Regarding the NULL, I think it actually violates C11 6.5.15/3. You aren't allowed to mix integer and pointers in the ?: operator. GCC gives a compiler error.

Comment: @ChristianRau If someone intentionally writes code that doesn't make sense, then the possible uses of the ?: operator is the least one of their problems...

Answer (score 0):

For C# says:
Syntax:

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

And it says about first_expression and second_expression:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Comment: Who said anything about C#? `And it says...` Who says?

Comment: @Lundin *"Who said anything about C#?"* - The question in an earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to evaluate a nullable object type instead of `bool`, you could always write:

```
variable = myVar ?? i;
```

Hacky/cludgey/impractical - probably all 3, but for the sake of this question it's a way of omitting an 'else'.

Answer (score 0):

Try: null lambda.

```
auto null_lambda = [](){return;};
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
vector<int> c;

a > c ? b = c.push_back(b) : null_lambda();
```